# How to force yarn to override yarn.lock version and install latest?

Tags: yarnpkg

I would like to keep all other package versions in tact, but upgrade one single package to the most recent version. How can I do that using yarn?

I know I can delete yarn.lock, and then run `yarn install`, but I think that will upgrade *every* package, which I don't want. I just want the most recent version of `node-sass`, and for that to override the version I have in `yarn.lock`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/usage#upgrading-a-dependency):

```
yarn up [package]
yarn up [package]@[version]
yarn up [package]@[tag]
```

So, to upgrade node-sass, you should run:

```
yarn up node-sass
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Rodrigo Merlone does not work with yarn-classic. For yarn-classic, a resolution is required.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "left-pad": "1.0.0",
    "c": "file:../c-1",
    "d2": "file:../d2-1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "d2/left-pad": "1.1.1",
    "c/**/left-pad": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

More info:
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/